# how to Nginx Cache works with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, performance, nginx, fastcgi

I'm Really confused about how **Nginx Cache** interacts with **(php) Laravel** all I know that Nagix uses **FastCGI** to Cache dynamic pages and serve it as static for optimal performance and Laravel have good Caching component.

> There's a  [package](https://github.com/karchz/ngxcache) : Nginx Cache Controller for Laravel 4, but it outdated
>   :(

My Question is how php (Laravel) interacts with cache like - prevent page or request from cached or purge the cache - etc....?

Answer (score -1):

Nginx & Apache both are nginx is faster response than apache nginx have different rewrite rule with laravel nginx is good choice 
nginx have fastcgi so you can use same like apache 
here is 1 understanding link
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-and-implementing-fastcgi-proxying-in-nginx
sorry for my bad english
hope this help you